# Audio Input to a Java/Processing Applet through Browser?

Tags: java, audio, applet, processing, minim

Is there a straightforward way to do this?
I am working in Processing, and I'm trying to get audio input using the Minim library to create visualizations; this works fine when it's just a Java app running normally, but it, rather obviously, does not translate well to a browser.

For those of you who are unfamiliar with Processing, it is just a graphics API for Java, so anything I could do in Java I could theoretically do in Processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a lib that I think might work for this:
http://www.softsynth.com/jsyn/